# Can a local variable have the same name as a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

GCC, clang and VS2013 compile the snippet below:

```
namespace A{}
int main()
{
    int A;
}
```

However [namespace.alias]/4 says the following:

> A *namespace-name* or *namespace-alias* shall not be declared as the
>   name of any other entity in the same *declarative region*.

and

[basic.scope.declarative]/1 says:

> Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a
>   *declarative region*, which is the largest part of the program in which that name is *valid*, that is, in which that name may be used as
>   an unqualified name to refer to the same entity.

That is, I have the impression that the `int` variable in `main()` cannot have the same name as the namespace `A`. Observe that the example in [basic.scope.declarative]/2 seems to corroborate this when it says

> The *declarative region* of the first j includes the entire example.

Comment: I don't think they are in the same declarative region. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630201/whats-the-difference-between-declarative-region-and-scope and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376399/c11-3-3-1p4-declarations-in-same-declarative-region

Comment: `j` is outside main in that example. Try putting your `int A;` at global scope to compare.

Comment: For what it's worth, **[namespace.alias]/4** paragraph no longer exists in C++14.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik N4140 has it.

Comment: See also "**[basic.lookup.udir]/1** In a *using-directive* or *namespace-alias-definition*, during the lookup for a *namespace-name* or for a name in a *nested-name-specifier* only namespace names are considered." If namespace names could never be hidden, this paragraph (which is already present in C++03) would be pointless.

Comment: `N4140 has it` but N4296 doesn't.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I was under the impression N4296 was post-C++14

Comment: @IgorTandetnik N4296 is not C++14. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29115882/1042389

Comment: This could be. In any case, that paragraph appears to be in error and was subsequently removed. It doesn't make much sense to carve a special exception in name lookup rules for namespace names. There's also "**[basic.lookup]/1** The name lookup rules apply uniformly to all names (including ... *namespace-names*...)"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik see [dr 1795](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1795)

Comment: @Angew the wording was a defect and that is why it was removed, see y answer below

Answer (score 7):

From [basic.scope.declarative], the definition of a "declarative region" is:

> Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a declarative region, which is the largest part
>   of the program in which that name is valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualified name
>   to refer to the same entity.

The restriction is, emphasis mine:

> Given a set of declarations **in a single declarative region**, each of which specifies the same unqualified name
>   — they shall all refer to the same entity, or all refer to functions and function templates

Going back to your example. If we annotate the two declarative regions, we have:

```
namespace A{}    + region #1
                 |
int main()       |           +
{                |           |
    int A;       |           | region #2               
                 |           |
}                +           +
```

The declarative regions for `namespace A` (#1) and `int A` (#2) are different (the second is a strict subset of the first, but that doesn't matter). Since they are different, the restriction on having a single name doesn't apply. There is one single `A` in #2 and one single `A` in #1.

If we, however, moved `int A` to be in the same declarative region:

```
namespace A {}     +   the only declarative region. even though the
int A;             |   potential scope of "int A" does not include
                   |   "namespace A", the declarative region does.
int main() {       |   The intent of this is expressed in the example
                   |   in [basic.scope.declarative]/2:
                   |        int main() {
                   |            int i = j, j;
                   |            j = 42;
                   |        }
                   |
                   |   "The declarative region of the [j] includes all 
                   |    the text between { and }, but its potential scope
}                  +    excludes the declaration of i."
```

That would violate [basic.scope.declarative]/4, and both gcc and clang correctly reject the code with:

> error: redefinition of '`A`' as different kind of symbol

Note that as [Vaughn Cato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775091/can-a-local-variable-have-the-same-name-as-a-namespace/29776086?noredirect=1#comment47684643_29776086) points out, there is an [active defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#554) about the wording for declarative region.

Comment: Wouldn't a strict reading of this imply that even the second example is valid, since the region for which int A is valid is one line less than the region for which namespace A is valid?

Comment: @VaughnCato The scope is one line less, but the declarative region is the same. I believe that's the intended meaning, at the least.

Comment: @VaughnCato The example indicates that the intent is the declarative region is the same: "The declarative region
of the second declaration of `j` (the `j` immediately before the semicolon) includes all the text between `{` and
`}`, but its potential scope excludes the declaration of i". The declarative region includes the declaration of `i`, even though its scope does not.

Comment: @Barry `Since they are different, the restriction on having a single name doesn't apply` I can't see how this could be inferred from the **largest part** you highlighted above.

Comment: @Angew: I agree the examples indicate that is the intent, but it seems to be inconsistent with the definition, or perhaps the definition of "valid" is not what I would expect. It seems like if the definition of "declarative region" is correct, it would imply that the local j is valid before the name appears within the braces.

Comment: @LeonTrotski Yeah makes more sense to emphasis **single declarative region**. Changed that.

Comment: @Barry `[ Note: A namespace name or a class template name must be unique in its declarative region (7.3.2, Clause 14).—end note ]` in [basic.scope.declarative]/4.

Comment: @LeonTrotski Yes is exactly the same as [basic.scope.declarative]/4... except what I quoted isn't a note. `namespace A` and `int A` are in separate declarative regions, so uniqueness isn't violated.

Comment: Turns out there's already a defect report on the definition of "declarative region" being inconsistent: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#554. It's been there since 2006, but just has never been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The first quote you mention *[namespace.alias]/4* was actually there to cover extension namespaces and is the subject of a defect report and was subsequently removed and replaced with more specific wording. We can see from [DR 1795](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1795) which says:

> According to 7.3.1 [namespace.def] paragraph 2,
>
> > The identifier in an original-namespace-definition shall not have been previously defined in the declarative region in which the
> >     original-namespace-definition appears.
>
> Apparently the intent of this requirement is to say that, given the
>   declarations
>
> ```
> namespace N { }
> namespace N { }
> ```
>
> the second declaration is to be taken as an
>   extension-namespace-definition and not an
>   original-namespace-definition, since the general rules in 3.3.1
>   [basic.scope.declarative] cover the case in which the identifier has
>   been previously declared as something other than a namespace.

and tells us that `3.3.1` [basic.scope.declarative] covers the case you are referring to, which it does in paragraph `1`:

> Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a declarative region, which is the largest part
>   of the program in which that name is valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualified name
>   to refer to the same entity. In general, each particular name is valid only within some possibly discontiguous
>   portion of program text called its scope. To determine the scope of a declaration, it is sometimes convenient
>   to refer to the potential scope of a declaration. The scope of a declaration is the same as its potential scope
>   unless the potential scope contains another declaration of the same name. In that case, the potential scope
>   of the declaration in the inner (contained) declarative region is excluded from the scope of the declaration
>   in the outer (containing) declarative region.

and `3`:

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> - they shall all refer to the same entity, or all refer to functions and function templates;

Comment: Having this question brought to my attention by M.M's edit, I did not believe the accepted answer, until I read the citations in yours. Top marks. The point that declarative region rules are "aware" of "overrides" of names in more inner scopes is the key point, and nobody else proved that.

Comment: Actually on further reading Nathan did but yours is still clearer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example 3.3.1(2) just below 3.3.1(1)

```
int j = 24;
int main() {
    int i = j, j;
    j = 42;
}
```

It is noted as

> the identifier j is declared twice as a name (and used twice). The declarative region of the first j includes the entire example. **The potential scope of the first j begins immediately after that j and extends to the end of the program, but its (actual) scope excludes the text between the , and the }.** The declarative region of the second declaration of j (the j immediately before the semicolon) includes all the text between { and }, but its potential scope excludes the declaration of i. The scope of the second declaration of j is the same as its potential scope.

Pay attention to what it say the scope of the name is.  Emphasis mine.

So in the global space of the program you have a name `A` that is your namespace.  Then you enter the scope of `main()` and the `namespace A` is still a valid name until in the declaration of the `int A` has been seen.  Once that happens in the scope of main the namespace `A` will be hidden and any unqualified calls to `A` will be to the `int` that was declared.

Comment: Note, notes and examples are not normative and the question is tagged language lawyer, so I would expect at least some normative text in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The largest scope that your `int A` is valid is the entire scope of `main`, so its declarative region is `main`. The namespace is valid at global scope and as such is not in the same declarative scope. Note that while the scopes overlap, they are not the *same* scope. The code looks valid to me given your quotes from the standard.

Comment: Why not? Isn't `using namespace A;` valid inside main()? Then the block enclosed by main() is part of the declarative region containing the definition of namespace A.

Comment: [namespace.alias]/4 doesn't say anything about scopes, but about declarative regions.